# How to count free space in div?

Tags: javascript, text

Is it possible to count width in px of this free space in a div?

https://www.screencast.com/t/fG1C7uTHjJF

HTML:

```
<div>Hello world! Code is my life</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine i've  div element with id=myDiv:

```
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
// re-use canvas object for better performance
var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas =   document.createElement("canvas"));
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.font = font;
var metrics = context.measureText(text);
return metrics.width;
```

}

var remainingSize=$('#mydiv').width() - getTextWidth($('#mydiv').text(),30);

Comment: This code give us number of spaces. I need width in px

Comment: Did this answer help you?

Comment: no, but thx for your help. I think there is no way to resolve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
var length = $('#mydiv').text().split(" ").length-1;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The script counts the number of words and returns the count reduced by one. The OP would like to know if it's possible to treat words as inline-block elements and calculate the free available space of each row relative to a parent container.